# How to configure health checks for mosquitto-eclipse running on AWS ECS in the task definition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, amazon-ecs, mosquitto

Right now i have deployed mosquitto-eclipse successfully on Amazon `ECS` but i want to configure health checks in the task definition

**Note** mosquitto uses port 1883 and port 9001

**Issue**

commands like curl are not installed in the mosquitto-eclipse image,so something like

`CMD-SHELL curl -f http://localhost:1883 || exit 1`

wont work because curl is not installed

**question**

how do i correctly health check my mqtt mosquitto from the task definition ?

**tried**

`/ # wget --quiet --spider --tries=1 "http://localhost:9001"`

but i get this error

`wget: error getting response: Address not available`

also something worth mentioning i have username and password set up in mosquitto say

`username:abc`

`password:xyz`

so maybe that is why wget is failing ? if so how do i specify the username and password in wget ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? There is no point running the health check from within the container. (Also you can't use `curl` to connect to port 1883, it will not respond to HTTP commands, port 9001 will)

Comment: lets say websockets get closed for out of memory... so i want to write a health check to ensure mosquitto is working fine and if not i want to restart the container... or add an alarm to that healthcheck so i can increase the memory allocated to that container

Comment: I don't understand your first premise, what do you mean about "websockets get closed because of out of memory"? If the broker suffers a OOM it will exit and the container will be restarted.

Comment: Still i'd like to configure a health check is there anyway it can be done ? maybe using mosquitto clients somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you don't. HealthChecks are what are run against your container by another service. For instance your ALB load balancer to decide if the container task is healthy and to route traffic there. You don't make requests to your container from inside your container, that's the end of the story.

However, nothing stops you have from having an health check endpoint in your service which returns data when requested. You would need to compose a container which runs two services, the Mosquitto and a second webservice to monitor the container.

However, based on what you are looking for, you should be monitoring the service from outside of the ECS task. You can either deploy another task or use the built in metrics/alarms to determine how to adjust the autoscaling when necessary. Don't build your own solution.

Further, you don't and shouldn't deploy mosquitto to AWS, because AWS already natively supports MQTT message brokers via [Amazon MQ service](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/?amazon-mq.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&amazon-mq.sort-order=desc)

Comment: As far as I can tell Amazon MQ doesn't support mqtt 5, because it runs ActiveMQ Classic. Maybe this could be a reason to run mosquitto after all